# How can I prove that if $\int_{[0,1]} f~d\nu\leq C\int_{[0,1]} f~d\mu$ then the measures are absolutely continuous?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, borel-measures, absolute-continuity

> Let us consider $T:[0,1]\rightarrow [0,1]$ be a continuous map. Let $\mu, \nu$ be $T$ invariant probability measures on $\mathcal{B}([0,1])$. I want to show that if there exists $D>0$ s.t. $\int_{[0,1]} f~d\nu\leq C\int_{[0,1]} f~d\mu$ for all $f:[0,1]\rightarrow \Bbb{R_+}$ continuous then $\nu \ll \mu$ (absolutely continuous).

My idea was first to consider some simple functions $f=1_{[a,b]}$ where $[a,b]\subset [0,1]$. Then assume that there exists $C$ s.t. $\nu([a,b])\leq C\mu ([a,b])$. Now I need to pick an arbitrary $A\in \mathcal{B}([0,1])$ and assume $\mu(A)=0$. I want to show that $\nu(A)=0$. I thought that since sets of the form $[a,b]$ generates $\mathcal{B}([0,1])$ we know that $A$ can be written as unions and intersections of intervalls $[a,b]$. But I'm not really sure if this can be done like this. Because I would then try to use operations of the measure on unions and intersections to conclude that $\nu(A)\leq C\mu(A)$ which allows us to conclude in this case if we assume $\mu(A)=0$.

But does this work?

Comment: Try to see why you can take $f$ to be a characteristic function of an interval (which is usually not continuous) and check if you can replace those intervals by an arbitrary Borel set.

Comment: @blamethelag I'm a bit confused, do I need to assume that there exists $C$ s.t. $\nu(I)=\int_{[0,1]} 1_I d\nu \leq C\int_{[0,1]} 1_i d\mu= \mu(I)$  and show that if $\mu(I)=0$ then $\nu(I)=0$ which is obvious? (we let $I$ be an interval)

Comment: 1) I don’t see a $C$ in your last comment after you assumed it existed. 2) You assumed the existence of a $C$ in your post. 3) In your post, in the statement of your problem, you assumed that some inequality holds for continuous functions $f$ but then apply it to a characteristic which may happen to be discontinuous. Do you know if this is legitimate?

Comment: @blamethelag 1) sorry I forgott the $C$. 3)ah so I can approximate the characteristif function by a sequence of continuous functions $f_n$ s.t. $|f_n(x)-f(x)|\rightarrow 0$ then $\nu(I)=\int 1_i d\nu =\lim_n \int f_n d\nu\leq \lim C \int f_n d\mu=C\int 1_I d\mu= C\mu(I)$ where I used dominated convergence.

Comment: You should be more carefull: your notations are sloppy and you did not specified what kind of convergence it is. I assume it is pointwise which is ok but not for arbitrary Borel sets (by Baire theory the discontinuity locus of a pointwise limit of continuous functions is meager). If you relax this to almost everywhere pointwise concergence then you can do this for arbitrary Borel sets and you are done

Comment: @blamethelag ah sure sorry clearly we need $|f_n(x)-f(x)|\rightarrow 0$ for a.e. $x$. But then I can do what I did above right? But now I need to consider a general measurable set $A$ right?

Comment: @blamethelag My further idea was first to argue that I can consider a general measurable set without any problems. I would say this is possible by the fact that the borel simga algebra is generated by such intervalls (do i need more here). Then I know that the statement holds for $1_A$. But I know that for a positive continuous function there is an increasing sequence of simple functions which approximate it. Hence the statement also holds for general continuous $f$. Or do I miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $K$ is a compact subset of $[0,1]$ then there is a decreasing sequence $(f_n)$ of continuous functions with pointwise limit $1_K$ (the indicator of $K$). This shows $\nu(K)\le C\mu(K)$ for all compact $K$. Now use inner regularity of $\nu$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Couldn‘t I do it as I wrote in the last comment above? Because I‘m not really used to regularity.  

It would be nice if you could tell me what to do regarding to my last comment. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You have $\int f\,d\nu\le C\int f\,d\mu$ for continuous $f\ge 0$, and would like to show that this inequality persists for bounded measurable $f$, and then take $f=1_A$ for a Borel set $A$ with $\mu(A)=0$. Because the continuous functions generate the Borel sets, if it were $=$ you were trying to show (not $\le$) you could use the Monotone Class Theorem. But I don't see how to use the MCT to extend an *inequality*.